# How to get similar result from ->get() and ->find($id) in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a list of category. If user click on a category, user will see a list of users related to that category, users table has a `category_id` field. I am using below code in controller for this.

```
$category = Category::with('users')->find($id);
```

But there is a link `All Category`, if user click on that link user will see all the users of all categories.I am using below code in controller for this.

```
$category = Category::with('users')->get();
```

Both users of single category and all category is using same View (HTML file). Pagination is needed for both users of single category and all category.

I need similar result from `->get()` and `->find($id)` to display result in same View (HTML file).

How can I do that ?

Comment: If a category can have multiple users and a user can be related to multiple categories, why is not there many to many relationship?

Comment: @UjwalKadariya, why many to many relationship needed ? I just need similar result from `->get()` and `->find($id)` to display result in same View (HTML file).

Answer (score 1):

So the latter returns a collection while the first one returns just an instance of a Category, so you have couple of options, not sure if this would work:

```
$category = Category::with('users')->find([$id]);
```

Passing an array to `find` returns a collection I believe, or try this instead:

```
$category = Category::with('users')->where('id', $id)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks @nakov for your reply. Actually I need an Array type result from both. So that I can count values and iterate to display values.

Comment: A collection is an array on steroids :) so that's what the result will be above.. you can use `$category->count()` and you can iterate over it as you would normally do with an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way:

```
$category = Category::with('users')->where('id', $id)->get();
```

Or make an empty object:

```
$obj = collect();
```

Then push to this collection:

```
$category = Category::with('users')->find($id);
$object->push($category)
```

Comment: Thanks @meph for your reply. Actually I need an Array type result from both. So that I can count values and iterate to display values.

Answer (score 1):

The point is, `find` returns one `row` as an instance of the `Model` while `get` returns a `collection` of instances of the `Model`. If you read documentation carefully, you will find it. So one solution is after using `find`, `push` it to an empty collection. Other answer showed this way.

Since you need **pagination** in both purpose,

Instead of using `Category::with('users')->find($id);`, use

```
Category::with('users')->where('id', $id)->paginate();
```

And instead of `Category::with('users')->get();` query, use

```
Category::with('users')->paginate();
```

Comment: Thanks @MASh for your reply. Actually I need an Array type result from both. So that I can count values and iterate to display values.

Comment: As far as I understood your use case, you better use `pagination`. This will give you an array with your data and other stuffs. Check https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/pagination for details